# Force Header Files to Compile as C++ in Xcode

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, c, xcode

I have an Xcode project for iOS in Xcode 7.0 that contains Objective-C, C++, and C code. Xcode tries to compile the C++ header files with the extension .h (not .hpp) as C header files which generates errors.

How do I fix this? There should be a setting for which files should be compiled as which language.

Comment: Are the headers .h or .hpp?

Comment: They are .h. Will changing them to .hpp help?

Comment: You can change the type of an individual file under the "File inspector".

Comment: I have not used Xcode so I can't answer that but I have been under the impression .hpp is used to show that the header is a C++ header.

Comment: Changing them to `.hpp` should also work.

Comment: Headers aren't compiled in isolation. How they're interpreted depends on where you include them.

Comment: Changing the extension to .hpp did not work.

Comment: A way to fix the problem is to write a makefile.  Where the makefile has the appropriate rules for each type of source file and only the appropriate files are passed to the appropriate rule.

Comment: @jBot-42 After changing to `.hpp` did you check the file inspector. It should say that the type is *"Default - C++ Header"*. Also, since you've been playing around with the build settings, you might want to start a new project, so that all the build settings are back to their defaults.

Comment: Will leaving them as .h and changing the file type to 'C++ Header' work?

Comment: I'd have to see your code. I think that the comment by @molbdnilo is the real answer.

Comment: You shall not compiler headers themselves. They are always `#include`d in an implementation file, so the language is determined by that file.

Comment: Apparently not. They are included in a .cpp file with C++ code.

Comment: Does XCode have a facility for building and relying upon "precompiled headers"?  If so, try turning it off.  Especially do so if any of the same headers are included both in C source files and in C++ source files.  Otherwise, I think we've exhausted the alternatives we can suggest without you presenting example code with which the failure can be reproduced, and the actual error messages that lead you to conclude that files are being compiled for the wrong language.

Comment: I have partially fixed the issue, but it seems like what I need to do now is force certain header files to compile as C++ and not C. **How is this done in Xcode?**

Comment: How are you determining that the files are compiled "as C" when you include them in a C++ source file? You haven't mentioned anything concrete about the actual behaviour you're experiencing.

Comment: C++ method declarations create errors saying that the colon is an invalid character.

Comment: What if the header file is a precompiled header? @molbdnilo It is compiled in isolation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Individually header files doesn't compiled. Compiled source files where they included. If you include them in .c they will be compiled like C, if in .m - like Objective-c, if in .cpp - like C++, if in .mm - like Objective-C++.

It doesn't matter how you name them .h or .hpp.

If you have some portion of C++ code in h-file- you should put it in

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#endif
```

If you have some portion of Objective-C code in h-file you should put it in

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
#endif
```

This will make code inside this statement invisible for other languages.

You can find this statement in Xcode's generated pch-file.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The asker asked how to force compiling header file with specified language instead of how to port codes between different situations.