# How to compile .h file which has struct definition with default values

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, clang, objective-c++

I'm trying to use a 3rd party sample code as part of my Objective-C application.

However, when trying to compile my project I get a lot of compiler errors.
The objc syntax that is used in the sample is quite strange and I believe that it is compiled as something else within the project.

For example, as part of the header file the struct definition has default values:

File.h

```
struct Options
{
   int count = 100;
}
...
```

In their project, the above header file would compile just fine, but when I try to compile it I see an Xcode error:

```
Expected ';' at end of declaration list
```

I'm not an objective-c expert, but from what I've read and also found as part of other posts `data types` cannot have default values, but somehow it compiles fine in the Xcode sample app.

Please let me know if you need more info or other examples of what would compile fine in their project and doesn't work when  I copy and paste the code into mine.

Edit:

[Force Header Files to Compile as C++ in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32827389/force-header-files-to-compile-as-c-in-xcode)

> Individually header files doesn't compiled. Compiled source files where they included. If you include them in .c they will be compiled like C, if in .m - like Objective-c, if in .cpp - like C++, if in .mm - like Objective-C++.

My issue was that I was using this header file into a `.m` file which compiles it to an Objective-C standard. When I change the extension to `.mm` everything worked fine.

Comment: this is actually a C question. Where objective-C is based on C and objective-C++ is based on C++ of course, where different rules apply. in example the rules for overwriting.

Comment: and consider that the file endings `.m`, `.mm`, `.c` of your implementation file defines what language the header file is for. So Xcode can handle all of them, even mixed up. To keep it clear what is what sometime there are specific compiler directives (`#ifdef`) used.

Answer (score 0):

When you think of objective-C as actually being C its more clear why defaults are not set in .h files
This does not apply to the rules of default sizes which are needed when no flexible memory allocation for a data type is available by default, like for (as is) most data types in C.

Even this two sentences already show the difficulty to distinguish what is meant with `"default"`.
Which is why you end up with definition of initiation processes and functions to declare what exactly is "default" in the other file.

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

typedef struct {
   int count;
} Options;

typedef struct {
   int foo;
   Options bar[100]; 
} Foo;


struct Bar {
    Foo lotsof;
}

void MyInitiationFunction(Bar *b); 
// definition of MyInitiationFunction in .m/.c file

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

but there is the concept of `enum` that can trick your mind where defined enumeration default states are what you build some stuff on, which is not a value.