# G711Codec.h:44:1: error build: unknown type name 'class'; did you mean 'Class'?

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode

want to add some Camera SDK in my swift project.. but cant solve this error..

> libAndHeaders/MediaPlayer/G711Codec.h:42:1: error build: unknown type name 'class'; did you mean 'Class'?

maybe this is cpp header file or some other file. when i include this in my Objectice-c header file then it gives me this err..

```
/*
    G711解码库
*/

#ifndef _G711_CODEC_H_
#define _G711_CODEC_H_



#define word16 short
#define word32 int

#define Word16 short
#define Word32 int

#define HI_VOICE_MAX_FRAME_SIZE       (480+1)    /* dont change it */

#define BIAS        (0x84)      /* Bias for linear code. */
#define CLIP         8159

#define SIGN_BIT    (0x80)      /* Sign bit for a A-law byte. */
#define QUANT_MASK  (0xf)       /* Quantization field mask. */
#define NSEGS       (8)     /* Number of A-law segments. */
#define SEG_SHIFT   (4)     /* Left shift for segment number. */
#define SEG_MASK    (0x70)      /* Segment field mask. */

static int seg_aend[8] = {0x1F, 0x3F, 0x7F, 0xFF,
    0x1FF, 0x3FF, 0x7FF, 0xFFF};
static int seg_uend[8] = {0x3F, 0x7F, 0xFF, 0x1FF,
    0x3FF, 0x7FF, 0xFFF, 0x1FFF};

/* HISI_VOICE codec type */

/* Real-time transport protocol(RTP) */
#define G711_A                        0x01  /* 64kbps G.711 A, see RFC3551.txt  4.5.14 PCMA */
#define G711_U                        0x02  /* 64kbps G.711 U, see RFC3551.txt  4.5.14 PCMU */
#define G711_ORG_A                    0x41  /* original version 64kbps G.711 A */
#define G711_ORG_U                    0x42  /* original version 64kbps G.711 U */

typedef int (*G711_Decoder)(int sample);

class G711Codec 
{
```

check this screenshot
[image: Xcode ScreenShot]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Force Header Files to Compile as C++ in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32827389/force-header-files-to-compile-as-c-in-xcode)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it´s a c++ header. You can mix obj-c and c++ if you need to (such source files need to have .mm extension, so that the compiler recognizes them), but probably you can choose another (obj-c) framework for what you need.